# How to prevent ExtJS changing the value of an object when using a Model?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs5

I'm currently migrating Extjs 4.2 to Extjs 6.2 and I'm simply trying to save a record. My code works just fine in **ExtJs 4.2**, but it fails in **ExtJs 6.2** when trying to create. The problem is that the value of **data**  changes in Extjs 6.2 after passing it to Model. Please see attached picture.

**PICTURE 1:**

Take a look at value of data **BEFORE** hitting the Model (Line 371)

[image]

**PICTURE 2:**

Value of data **AFTER** hitting the Model (Line 371)

[image]

You noticed that the value of data changes. Well this doesn't happen in ExtJs 4.2 and I want it to behave the same way in ExtJs 6.2.

Here's my code:

**folder.js**

```
if (folderNameIsValid(s)) 
    {
    // create the new folder
        var data = {
        typeId : me.typeId,
        name : s,
        loaded : true
    };

    if (me.clientId) data.clientId = me.clientId;
    if (me.userId) data.userId = me.userId;
    if (me.recordId) data.recordId = me.recordId;
    if (me.empId) data.employeeId = me.empId;
    if (pn !== rn) data.parentFolderId = pn.get('folderId');

    var node = Ext.create('App.model.FolderTreeNodeDisplay', data);

    node.save({
        callback : function()
        {
        pn.appendChild(node);

        pn.expand();

        sm.select(node);
    }
});
}
```

**Here's code for Model:**

```
Ext.define('App.model.FolderTreeNodeDisplay', 
{
extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
idProperty: 'folderId',

fields : [
    {name: 'folderId', type: 'int', useNull: false},
    {name: 'typeId', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'recordId', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'employeeId', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'userId', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'clientId', type: 'int', useNull: true},
    {name: 'permanent', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'N'},
    {name: 'fixed', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'N'},
    {name: 'active', type: 'string', defaultValue: 'Y'},
    {name: 'name', type: 'string', convert: Ext.htmlDecode},
    {name: 'parentFolderId', type: 'int', useNull: true},

    // domain fields
    {name: 'createdBy', type: 'string', persist: false},
    {name: 'creationDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c', useNull: true, persist: false},
    {name: 'lastUpdatedBy', type: 'string', persist: false},
    {name: 'lastUpdatedDate', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c', useNull: true, persist: false},

    // node fields
    {name: 'iconCls', type: 'string', persist: false},
    {name: 'leaf', persist: false},
    {name: 'expanded', persist: false},
    {name: 'parentId', persist: false}
],

proxy: {
    type: 'rest',
    api: { 
        create  : '/rs/rest/folder/create'
    },
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'data'
    }
    }
   });
```

**My question is:** 
What do I need to change/update in my Model so the value of data remains the same after hitting Line 371 and **NOT** pull all of the random data that you see in picture 2

Any ideas on what I'm missing or need to change in my Model? Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified a URL for the proxy. The default in the framework is to use the model name.

Comment: Trimboli, actually I solved my issue. Your input helped!. Thanks

Comment: Hi Evan I was wondering if you could please help me with a mouseover on panel issue I'm having? Here's the question's link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808220/how-to-change-image-on-panel-when-doing-mouseover-using-css-extjs